# MacFUSE: Keepalive?

Tags: shell, timeout, keep-alive, macfuse

Is there a way to configure MacFUSE to keep a mounted volume alive if the remote host is set to break the connection due to inactivity? If there is no direct way to configure this, would there be a way to write a script to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Fuse4x](http://fuse4x.org). It contains several fixes over MacFUSE. It is possible that this issue with sshfs is fixed there. You might ask fuse4x.org forum as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something quick and dirty based on Maksim's answer.   Copy and paste this code into Scipt Editor and save it as an application. If you need to quit it before the 900 minutes are up you'll have to force quit it.

```
repeat 900 times
    do shell script "touch path/to/file/dummyfile.txt"
    --sleep for 1 minute
    do shell script "/bin/sleep 60"
end repeat
```

Comment: By the way, just want to let you know it does not work. MacFUSE still times out. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use "touch [filename]" just to touch file on the drive. Use this command in Apple script and it should work fine. I have not tested it yet. When i finish writing this script, all edit my post.